# Fix the table size

Tags: tables

I want my table to be in center and the text be still readable, below the code I made for it, but it didn't work as you can see on the screenshot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\label{tab:methods}{
\begin{tabular}{c|l}   
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\textbf{Property/Method}}} & \textbf{Description} \\
\hline
\texttt{setItem()} & Adds a key-value pair to a Web Storage object. If the key already 
exists, its value is changed.\\
\hline
\texttt{getItem()} & Retrieves the value of a specified key from a Web Storage object. 
\\
\hline
\texttt{removeItem()} & Removes a specified key and the value associated with it from a 
Web Storage object.\\
\hline
\texttt{clear()} & Removes all the key-value pairs from the Web Storage object.\\
\hline
\texttt{key()} & Takes a zero-based index and returns key name at that index. \\
\hline
\texttt{length} & Returns the total number of key-value pairs from the Web Storage 
object. \\
\hline
\texttt{remainingSpace} & Returns the amount of storage space (in bytes) still available 
for storing data. This property is currently supported only by IE.\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Properties and Methods of \textit{Session Storage} and \textit{Local Storage}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

'''
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right column is too wide, obviously; the most obvious solution would be to use a column specifier that allows for line wrapping. Without packages you could use `p{3.2in}` or similar instead of `l`, but I suggest using the tabularx package so you can use the `X` column specifier which will expand to use the remaining width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\label{tab:methods}{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|X}
\hline
\textbf{Property/Method} & \textbf{Description} \\
\hline
\texttt{setItem()} & Adds a key-value pair to a Web Storage object. If the key already 
exists, its value is changed.\\
\hline
\texttt{getItem()} & Retrieves the value of a specified key from a Web Storage object. 
\\
\hline
\texttt{removeItem()} & Removes a specified key and the value associated with it from a 
Web Storage object.\\
\hline
\texttt{clear()} & Removes all the key-value pairs from the Web Storage object.\\
\hline
\texttt{key()} & Takes a zero-based index and returns key name at that index. \\
\hline
\texttt{length} & Returns the total number of key-value pairs from the Web Storage 
object. \\
\hline
\texttt{remainingSpace} & Returns the amount of storage space (in bytes) still available 
for storing data. This property is currently supported only by IE.\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\caption{Properties and Methods of \textit{Session Storage} and \textit{Local Storage}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabularx example]